# Hide field when export to CSV in SSRS with expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to hide one field in `SSRS` when I export the report. I know that if I put `NoOutput` property it will work but I have one more expression that I want to put for field visibility. I have this expression for my visibility and works fine for Excel, PDF,...

```
=IIf(Parameters!Limited.Value=false,false,true)
```

But when I export to `CSV` this doesn't work.
How can I improve this so that it also works for `CSV`?

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing if you find an answer to this.  I've struggled with it and researched it quite a bit, but nothing I've tried (including what Aldrin suggested below) seems to work.  I got Aldrin's code to work to hide things for an Excel export, but CSV seems to ignore everything I throw at it.

Comment: I find out that there is a problem with exporting to CSV format and i solved this by putting '****' in my sql store procedure , so when i will have export to CSV **** will be shown in my exported report. That's better than showing the real data

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that there are 2 types of exports in SSRS:

Data export - CSV and XML

Image based export - Word, PDF, Excel, TIFF, printing

The visibility property will only be read when you export to an image based export, and the data output property will only be read when using a data export.

If you can live with having the column there with the data being blank, then use Aldrin's method. If you want the column to not be there when exported and the columns you don't want to export is known in advanced, you're can use d b's way which is have 2 different tables, 1 for display but all the data is no output, the other output only for data export and visibility hidden.

If you need to do "No Output" dynamically, then that is pretty much impossible as a limitation of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script under Visibility property.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", True, False)
```

or Just this

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to conditionally hide a field for CSV output in SSRS.

But if it is very important to you, you can go through the trouble of creating 2 (or more) nearly-identical tables and show/hide the *entire tables* conditionally.

The contents of hidden *tables* (as opposed to rows and cells) do not get exported to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

> `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV", True, False)`

This doesn't work.

The only option is to create as many reports with the different column combinations then load the correct one dynamically.